Republishing Stack Overflow content as videos on YouTube
A YouTube content creator (there are probably others doing the same thing) is re-publishing Stack Overflow questions and answers on their channel.
In the details section of the videos, they write the following disclaimers:

Content (except music & images) licensed under CC BY-SA meta.stackexchange.com/help/licensing
Just wanted to thank those users featured in this video:
User X (https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXXX...)
User Y (https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXXX...)
User Z (https://stackoverflow.com/users/XXXXX...)
Trademarks are property of their respective owners.
Disclaimer: All information is provided "AS IS" without warranty of any kind. You are responsible for your own actions.
Please contact me if anything is amiss. I hope you have a wonderful day.

Is this acceptable use of Stack Overflow content and does it meet the requirements of attribution?
Under the CC BY-SA deed:

appropriate credit — If supplied, you must provide the name of the creator and attribution parties, a copyright notice, a license notice,
a disclaimer notice, and a link to the material.


indicate if changes were made — In 4.0, you must indicate if you modified the material and retain an indication of previous
modifications. In 3.0 and earlier license versions, the indication of
changes is only required if you create a derivative.

Don't these clauses imply that there needs to be a link back to the actual Q&A thread on Stack Overflow?
Is it acceptable to link back directly to individual user profiles, but not the content itself?
Does changing the questions to be un-cut-and-pasteable videos which don't reflect previous/future edits breach the "indicate if changes were made" clause?
It seems to me that ripping other people's contributions to auto-generate videos for profit whilst leaving all attribution in the fine-print is somehow unjust, but does it breach the terms and conditions of the SO licence?

"Does changing the questions to be un-cut-and-pasteable videos which don't reflect previous/future edits breach the "indicate if changes were made" clause?" - if the youtuber made changes to the questions or answers they should disclose that. "indicate if changes were made" refers to the copier's changes, it is not related to the edit history on StackOverflow.

"there are probably others doing the same thing", see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396232/youtube-channels-stealing-se-network-content

This is definitely not the first time we've had something like this.

I know of another one.

Has the person making the videos being told about that? Given that they mention the users in the description (I assume that's what you mean with details section?), they might not act in bad faith/may not be aware of how the requirements work so it might be possible to just tell them what they need to provide to comply with the license (and they might do that). See also the "Please contact me if anything is amiss." sentence in the description.

~42k videos of a man outside and then the text of posts from a site within the community, that's A+ content that is, @CPlus .

@ThomA it is pretty wild, I have not see so many videos with "No Views" in single channel before.

I was expecting a bit more creativity from the You Tuber to be honest, I can see a way to make this good, compliant, content but this isn't it!

I was expecting a robo-voice screenreader like the ones that scrape Reddit, and no appearance of a human at all. The fact that he actually records unique footage of himself for every video certainly sounds like a bottleneck. He's never gonna win the race to the bottom like that.

Are you implicitly asking who has standing for a DMCA takedown request? Well, quite a lot of requests.

Wow, these videos are real crap. A generic intro/outro and then just a video of scrolling slowly through the question and answers. Probably cheap and easy to produce in an automated workflow. In the last 24 hours he "produced" about 40 videos. And with every click on that crap we contribute to his income :(


Don't these clauses imply that there needs to be a link back to the actual Q&A thread on [Stack Overflow]?
Is it acceptable to link back directly to individual user profiles, but not the content itself?

This is not acceptable.  The creator is breaching the license in multiple ways.

The clearest issue is that they do, in fact, need to link to the specific page.  The terms of CC BY-SA 4.0 require a person sharing licensed material to provide "a URI or hyperlink to the Licensed Material to the extent reasonably practicable".  It is easily practicable to provide a link to the material itself: there is a "Share" link under every post for that exact purpose.
They also fail to indicate what the license is ("indicate the Licensed Material is licensed under this Public License, and include the text of, or the URI or hyperlink to, this Public License").  "CC BY-SA" is not a specific license; it is a family of multiple licenses, and Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange content is licensed under three different versions, depending on the post's creation date.  They provide a (non-clickable) URL to a page that explains how to tell what license a post is under, given the creation date of the post, but that date is not provided.

The fact that you can technically figure it out in most—though not necessarily all—cases by searching through all posts by all linked users surely does not qualify as a "reasonable manner" given that 1) this is an unreasonable burden on would-be users of the material, requiring them to either understand enough about the platform to perform the search or sift through potentially thousands of posts, and 2) there were far more reasonable ways to do this, such as simply linking to the post.


Finally, it is, at the very least, extremely questionable that they fail to indicate which author created which piece of content.  I can't point to a specific clause that this violates, so much as it violates the general idea of the attribution required by the license. Taken to an extreme, certainly there would be no credible argument that rehosting all Stack Overflow content alongside a list of all contributors to Stack Overflow, with no indication of who contributed what, would comply with the requirement to provide "identification of the creator(s) of the Licensed Material".  I'm not certain at what point, exactly, this would cross the line into failure to comply with the license.


Does changing the questions to be un-cut-and-pasteable videos which don't reflect previous/future edits breach the "indicate if changes were made" clause?

This part is probably fine.  They haven't made changes to the actual content (just the means by which it's displayed), so they aren't required to indicate that they put it in a video (alternatively, the fact that they put it in a video is arguably self-indicating: you can tell that it was put into a video by the fact that you are seeing it in a video).

Disclosure/disclaimer: While I work for the company that owns YouTube, 1) my work is generally unrelated to YouTube as a product or organization, and 2) this is my personal opinion written in my personal, non-professional capacity and does not necessarily represent the views of the company.  I am also not a lawyer and lack formal legal training generally.

After finding my content on several YouTube channels, I reported similar issues. I can summarize what I've learned from studying the licenses and talking to a lawyer.
Ryan's answer is very good and hits most of the key points.
There's another open question that Ryan didn't mention. What is the derivative work? Is it the video or is it the YouTube post? If the derivative work is the video, then the attribution should be in the video. Right now, there's no attribution in the video itself - it's all in the description. The lack of attribution in the video itself is problematic.
YouTube also doesn't make it possible to download videos natively. And my understanding is that they block downloaders. There's some uncertainty about the SA clauses and making the video available for further work. The SA clauses also extends to the music and images - the video as a whole becomes the derivative work. So you should be able to request the video, get it, and remix any portions of it. There could be license violations there.
Beyond the CC license, there may be other laws at play. For example, in some locales, deceptive trade practice laws may be used if it is unclear which content is yours, especially if you are a professional in the field that the content is about (eg, a professional software developer posting on Stack Overflow, Software Engineering, or another development related site). The rationale here is that it could negatively affect your professional reputation if you are associated with things that you didn't say.

yt-dlp is open source and currently works fine.  https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp . But youtube doesn't make it easy to download videos unless you pay for premium; there's a download button on every youtube video page, and clicking it opens a sign-up-for-premium dialog.

@PeterCordes Programs like yt-dlp violate the YouTube terms of service. Because the content isn't available to everyone who can see it in a format for adaptation, I'm not sure that YouTube is an appropriate platform for CC BY-SA content, especially if it's not mirrored elsewhere.

I agree with Thomas and Ryan.
There needs to be proper attribution in the video, and it needs to be explicit as to which content applies to which Stack Overflow author.
I don't want my username -- and I would assume this is the position of yourself and others -- associated with some random content on a channel or video which just happens to be cobbled in.
Without explicitly stating which part of the work applies, it leaves the implication that there is either support for the entire work or that any part of that content could be sourced from us. The channels should simply state where it comes from prior to covering the content.
I do believe that there is a path towards this being appropriate, given that proper attribution is provided, and the license is adhered to*. That is not even close to what is happening though.
Overall, it seems to be in bad taste.
*Appropriate: This would require the video to include the content author and link for the answer to be included prior to showing the content, along with a reference to the specific time of access and question. In addition, there would need to be a Chapter reference to the timestamp of the section where the content was shown, where the chapter reference (in the "More" section) includes a link and timestamp to when and where the content was accessed.

I don't see any additional info in your answer, besides agreeing with the other answers (and repeating what's already been said). Am I missing something?

@M-- Definitely missing some aspects here. Let's go through them. First and foremost, this platform is not designed to have one answer and then stop, it is designed to have multiple answers which bubble up. With regards to agreeing, I am not repeating. No one mentions being cross associated, what if there is violence or harmful messaging in the video?

@M-- Requesting that videos state the content source prior to showing it is an explicit note on how attribution would be introduced, whereas the other answers only note the lack of it and generally imply it should be somewhere.  I am also detailing here that there is a path towards doing this properly, something that is not noted in the other answers.

I don't agree with the "bubble up" statement, but I should say I am not entirely sure what do you mena by that. Putting that aside, cross association is covered in Ryan's answer (the final point). And simply saying there's a parh forward (which I don't agree with; see Thomas's answer) without enough clarification on that doesn't constitute as "extra info" in my book. Finally, I wanna make sure this doesn't get perceived as an ad hominem attack, I simply am asking a question to clarify your pont(s). Cheers.

"Some people propose answers. Others vote on those answers. If you see the right answer, vote it up. If an answer is obviously wrong (or inferior in some way), you vote it down. Very quickly, the best answers bubble to the top. The person who asked the question in the first place also has the ability to designate one answer as the “accepted” answer, but this isn’t required. The accepted answer floats above all the other answers." -Joel Spolsky from https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2008/09/15/stack-overflow-launches/

"Cross association" (quoted here since he doesn't actually mention that) in Ryan's answer is simply referring to a lack of identifying which author went to which content with regards to not properly linking them, but not with the risk of malicious content. For example when Oracle pulled all their ads on YouTube as a result of them being shown on a ISIS video.

That there is a path forward was the main reason I posted this. Disregarding personal feelings, so long as the license is abided by it is fair. As noted, it just needs to be prefaced during the visual content. I can expand on that since you think there isn't enough information (see edit)

I am glad our discussion resulted in that edit. This is now, imho, reads more like an independent answer.
